# Does jQuery support being run within an XML-document?

Tags: jquery, xml

As an outcome of a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812026/678801), I'm curious to if jQuery officially support being run in an XML-document, or is it just HTML-documents that are officially supported?

I know jQuery can be used for selecting DOM-elements etc. in XML-documents, but is it something that is officially supported and maintained?

*Note: I'm NOT talking about parsing XML using jQuery.*

Comment: The question is really [does javascript work in XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML), and that link even has a paragraph on libraries. XML on the other hand, is just a datatype, like JSON.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the reference, useful! It does indeed have a paragraph about libraries, unfortunately it doesn't answer whether jQuery maintain such support or not.

Comment: I'll bet you jQuery does'nt officially support being run in an XML file. It does have a built in parser for XML that creates XML that can be turned into a jQuery object etc. But running jQuery directly in an XML file probably won't work, and I would'nt think that it would be supported by the XML standards either.